# Bash script error: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, syntax

I want to run a command a number of times but with different arguments passed to it, so I wrote the following shell script to do that

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                   
for i in {4..6}
do
    for j in {0..10}
    do
        for k in {0..2}
        do
            root -b -l -q fitInvMass.C+($i,$j,$k)
        done
    done
done
```

However, this gives the following error

```
fit.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
fit.sh: line 8: `       root -b -l -q fitInvMass.C+($i,$j,$k)'
```

Comment: Next time you're trying to fix a syntax error do consider pasting your code into https://shellcheck.net

Comment: @roaima Interestingly enough, ShellCheck does not complain about the parenthesis.  It will accept using `fitInvMass.C+("$i","$j","$k")` with no diagnostics, even though `bash` will choke on it.

Comment: @Kusalananda I've logged a ticket with the shellcheck author for that one, as it seems to me it should at least recognise the parse failure

Comment: @roaima Good! Did you see the bit I added to my answer? In short, ShellCheck probably accepts it since `+(...)` is a valid extended globbing pattern.

Comment: ...which means that adding `shopt -s extglob` actually resolves the issue (assuming other options in their default state, and also no, don't do that, that's not a real fix)

Answer (score 4):

The parentheses are special characters in the shell syntax used in various operators and constructs such as in function definitions, command and process substitution, array assignments, arithmetic expressions, sub-shells etc.   If you need to use literal parentheses, you should quote them:

```bash
root -b -l -q "fitInvMass.C+($i,$j,$k)"
```

Using double quotes ensures that the variables in the string `fitInvMass.C+($i,$j,$k)` are expanded while the parenthesis is not interpreted as shell code.

---

The general suggestion is to use ShellCheck (https://www.shellcheck.net) to test shell code. It is pretty good at pointing out issues such as missing quotes etc.

In this case, though, ShellCheck would correctly point out that the three variable expansions in `fitInvMass.C+($i,$j,$k)` should be quoted, but it fails to spot that the parentheses also need quoting.  This means that it would happily accept the following modified line:

```bash
root -b -l -q fitInvMass.C+("$i","$j","$k")
```

(Or variations thereof where the variables are quoted but the parenthesis isn't.)

However, this would still fail to run, with the same diagnostic error message.  Why does ShellCheck not complain about it?

Well, `+(...)` is an extended globbing pattern which is a valid part of the `bash` shell's extended globbing syntax.  Unfortunately, ShellCheck seems to ignore that the `extglob` shell option needs to be enabled for the pattern to be valid and accepts it anyway. This is arguably a bug in ShellCheck.

Comment: Note that extglob can be enabled by default in some builds of bash.